# How to create excel export using sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> I need help in export data from table to excel file using sql query. 
>   and with header and footer.

I used `master..xp_cmdshell` with passing db name, table name, and path where I store excel file any buddy can solve this. and any other way like query through export data to excel.

I must say I want to solve problem using query only. because I require only query.

Comment: `I must say I can solve problem using query only. because I require only query.` - when you can solve your problem, then why asking here? Maybe you should make your problem clearer

Comment: sorry my mistake in explain a question.

Comment: I take and apply but its not working. any other ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need column headers the best way to export to a CSV file (which EXCEL will open) is by using sqlcmd. The syntax is something like:

```
c:\>sqlcmd -S servername -i c:\path\yourqueryfilename.sql -o C:\OutputPath\AFilename.csv -s","
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx to find the complete command line options available for SQLCMD.